# Anyway to add Epilog graphics outside of plot area without extending the axes?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'd like to be able to add a line below the x-axis of my plot but not have the y-axis extending down to cover this region (as it defaults to).

For example:

```
    Plot[Sin[x]^2, {x, 0, 2 π}, 
         Epilog -> {Thickness[0.02],Line[{{0, -0.1}, {5, -0.1}}]},
         PlotRange -> {{0, 2 π}, {-0.1, 1}}]
```

[image]

I don't want the bit of y-axis between 0 and my Line object to be drawn. Frustrated to not be able to figure this one out myself, I'm convinced I'm missing something simple!

Cheers

Comment: Try using [`ImagePadding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImagePadding.html).

Comment: @MarcoB + `PlotRangeClipping->False`.

Comment: closely related/duplicate [9346](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9346/5478)

Comment: Yup, I was being a fool. The addition of PlotRangeClipping->False and ImagePadding sorts it PROVIDED I remember to reset PlotRange to {{0,2pi},{0,1}}. Thanks, I'd already read that other qu several times but must have completely confused myself.